# Setting a class on a rails select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to set an HTML class to this rails select and i have tried many variations and nothing

```
<%= add.select :state,
      @states.map { |s| [ s.name, s.abbr ] },
      :class => 'state',
      :include_blank => true
%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your `html_options` should go after your `options`. Also, since you're specifying two hashes for your last two arguments, you should use curly braces to explicitly tell Ruby that they're two separate hashes. Try this:

```
<%= add.select(:state,
      @states.map { |s| [ s.name, s.abbr ] },
      { :include_blank => true },
      { :class => 'state' }
    )
%>
```